# Bootstrap Grid and HTML elements alignment

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a fixed static top navbar, and then I have another left navbar.
I'm trying to fill the rest of the page with text, but seems like the top navbar and the left navbar are hiding it.
I've tried placing the whole page in a container class, and then the top navbar in a row, and the left navbar in another row, then each row will have span6, so the other column next to the left navbar would be my text, but this still didn't work.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
    <head>
    <title>Tester</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <style>
      .dropdown-menu {
         background-image: url('http://127.0.0.1:3000/img/navbar_bg.jpg') !important;
         background-size: 100% !important;
     }
     .navbar-fixed-top {
        -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #8E8884;
        -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #8E8884;
        box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #8E8884;
        margin-bottom: 0 !important;
        background-image: url('http://127.0.0.1:3000/img/navbar_bg.jpg') !important;
        background-size: 100% !important;
        color: white
     }
body {
    background-color: rgb(214, 215, 219) !important;
}

.carousel-inner>img {
    height: 550px !important;
    width: 900px !important;
}

.carousel-control.left,.carousel-control.right {
    background-image: none !important;
}

.carousel-inner>.item>img {
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navbar-nav>li>a {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 1.3rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
    color: white !important;
}

.dropdown-menu>li>a {
    font-size: 20px;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-shadow: 0 -2px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.38);
    color: white !important;
}

.left_navbar {
    border-right: white;
    margin-top: 75px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    width: auto;
    display: inline-block;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #8E8884;
    -moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #8E8884;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 3px #8E8884;
    background-color: white;
    overflow: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
}
     </style>
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-inner navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="" width="30%" height="30%"></a>
        </div>

        <!-- Right Help section -->
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
              <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown">
                  <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Help <b class="caret"></b></a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                    <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                  </ul>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
       </ul> <!-- End of Right Help section -->       
      </div>
    </div>
   </div>

 <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked left_navbar">

          <li><a href="#">Email</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">System Username</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">Database Profile</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">System Password</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">location</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">xxxxxxxxx</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">Integration</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">Is sdsadsa Server</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">lalalalalalal</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">sdaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">weweaweaeweawewaewaewaeawewa</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">aaa</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">bbbbbbb</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">aaaaaaaaa</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">xzczzxcxzczxcz</a></li>

 </ul>

    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's bootstrap 3.x version so span6 is no more you have to use col-md-6 etc...read documentation. here is your updated working code

**[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/iFIZanEB/1/edit)**